# How to set Linux environment variables with Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

Hi I am trying to find out how to set environment variable with Ansible.

something that a simple shell command like this:

```
EXPORT LC_ALL=C
```

tried as shell command and got an error
tried using the environment module and nothing happend.

what am I missing

Answer (score 233, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this and from your question it's nor clear what you need.

**1. If you need environment variable to be defined PER TASK ONLY, you do this:**

> ```
> - hosts: dev
>   tasks:
>     - name: Echo my_env_var
>       shell: "echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE"
>       environment:
>         MY_ENV_VARIABLE: whatever_value
>
>     - name: Echo my_env_var again
>       shell: "echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE"
> ```

Note that `MY_ENV_VARIABLE` is available ONLY for the first task, `environment` does not set it permanently on your system.

```
TASK: [Echo my_env_var] ******************************************************* 
changed: [192.168.111.222] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE", ... "stdout": "whatever_value"}

TASK: [Echo my_env_var again] ************************************************* 
changed: [192.168.111.222] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE", ... "stdout": ""}
```

Hopefully soon using `environment` will also be possible on **play level**, not only task level as above.
There's currently a pull request open for this feature on Ansible's GitHub: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/8651

UPDATE: It's now merged as of Jan 2, 2015.

**2. If you want permanent environment variable + system wide / only for certain user**

You should look into how you do it in your Linux distribution / shell, there are multiple places for that. For example in Ubuntu you define that in files like for example:

- `~/.profile`
- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/profile.d` directory
- ...

You will find Ubuntu docs about it here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

After all for setting environment variable in ex. Ubuntu you can just use `lineinfile` module from Ansible and add desired line to certain file. Consult your OS docs to know where to add it to make it permanent.

Answer (score 48):

Here's a quick local task to permanently set key/values on `/etc/environment` (which is system-wide, all users, thus become is needed):

```
- name: populate /etc/environment
  lineinfile:

    path: "/etc/environment"
    state: present
    regexp: "^{{ item.key }}="
    line: "{{ item.key }}={{ item.value}}"

  with_items: "{{ os_environment }}"
  become: yes
```

and the vars for it:

```
os_environment:
  - key: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE 
    value : websec.prod_settings  
  - key: DJANGO_SUPER_USER 
    value : admin
```

and, yes, if you ssh out and back in, `env` shows the new environment variables.

p.s. It used to be `dest` as in:

```
    dest: "/etc/environment"
```

but see the comment

#### For the task only: inlining works, *some of the time*.

——————-

Note:  the stuff below is more an observation/experiment than a recommendation.
——————-

The first task is the equivalent to Michael's top voted answer.

The second doesn't work, but then again `foo=1 echo $foo` doesn't work in bash either (I suspect that's because `echo` is a builtin).

The third *does work*, as it does in bash, and takes very little effort.  **However...** when I tried doing this to [set a node variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54271093), it failed miserably until I used Michael's answer.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Echo my_env_var
      shell: "echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE"
      environment:
        MY_ENV_VARIABLE: value1  

    - name: Echo my_env_var inline, doesnt work in bash either
      shell: "MY_ENV_VARIABLE=value2 echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE"

    - name: set my_env_var inline then env
      shell: "MY_ENV_VARIABLE=value3 env | egrep MY_ENV"
```

#### output:

```
TASK [Echo my_env_var] *********************************************************
changed: [192.168.63.253] => changed=true 
  cmd: echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE
  stdout: value1

TASK [Echo my_env_var inline, doesnt work in bash either] **********************
changed: [192.168.63.253] => changed=true 
  cmd: MY_ENV_VARIABLE=value2 echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE
  stdout: ''

TASK [set my_env_var inline then env] ******************************************
changed: [192.168.63.253] => changed=true 
  cmd: MY_ENV_VARIABLE=value3 env | egrep MY_ENV
  stdout: MY_ENV_VARIABLE=value3
```

Comment: For first solution:
To confirm that the environment variables have been set,  check your /etc/environment file. 
`$ printenv`

Answer (score 47):

I did not have enough reputation to comment and hence am adding a new answer.
Gasek answer is quite correct. Just one thing: if you are updating the `.bash_profile` file or the `/etc/profile`, those changes would be reflected only after you do a new login.
In case you want to set the env variable and then use it in subsequent tasks in the same playbook, consider adding those environment variables in the `.bashrc` file.
I guess the reason behind this is the login and the non-login shells.
Ansible, while executing different tasks, reads the parameters from a `.bashrc` file instead of the `.bash_profile` or the `/etc/profile`.

As an example, if I updated my path variable to include the custom binary in the `.bash_profile` file of the respective user and then did a source of the file.
The next subsequent tasks won't recognize my command. However if you update in the `.bashrc` file, the command would work.

```
 - name: Adding the path in the bashrc files
   lineinfile: dest=/root/.bashrc line='export PATH=$PATH:path-to-mysql/bin' insertafter='EOF' regexp='export PATH=\$PATH:path-to-mysql/bin' state=present
 
-  - name: Source the bashrc file
   shell: source /root/.bashrc

 - name: Start the mysql client
   shell: mysql -e "show databases";
```

**This would work**, *but had I done it using profile files the `mysql -e "show databases"` would have given an error.*

```
- name: Adding the path in the Profile files
   lineinfile: dest=/root/.bash_profile line='export PATH=$PATH:{{install_path}}/{{mysql_folder_name}}/bin' insertafter='EOF' regexp='export PATH=\$PATH:{{install_path}}/{{mysql_folder_name}}/bin' state=present

 - name: Source the bash_profile file
   shell: source /root/.bash_profile

 - name: Start the mysql client
   shell: mysql -e "show databases";
```

**This one won't work**, *if we have all these tasks in the same playbook.*

Comment: Can you run all this tasks in the same playbook? as differents plays? or has to be in dif playbooks? i done trying this...

Answer (score 16):

This is the best option. As said Michal Gasek (first answer), since the pull request was merged (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/8651), 
we are able to set **permanent environment variables** easily by play level.

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
     - php
     - nginx
  environment:
    MY_ENV_VARIABLE: whatever_value
```

Answer (score 13):

For persistently setting environment variables, you can use one of the existing roles over at Ansible Galaxy. I recommend [weareinteractive.environment](https://galaxy.ansible.com/weareinteractive/environment).

Using ansible-galaxy:

```
$ ansible-galaxy install weareinteractive.environment
```

Using requirements.yml:

```
- src: franklinkim.environment
```

Then in your playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  roles:
    - role: franklinkim.environment
      environment_config:
        NODE_ENV: staging
        DATABASE_NAME: staging
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm installing [`krew` plugin manager](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/) and some of its plugin using `ansible` for a `Fish` shell. To install the plugins, I wanted to use the $PATH value as set by my previous task in `/.config/fish/config.fish`.

#### Error

Using `shell` module with [`executable` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-executable) was throwing:

```
stderr: |-
  error: unknown command "krew" for "kubectl"
  error: unknown command "krew" for "kubectl"
  error: unknown command "krew" for "kubectl"
```

#### Solution

1. add a line declaring the path to the krew bin in `/.config/fish/config.fish`

   ```
   - name: Add krew to $PATH
      lineinfile:
        path: '{{ home }}/.config/fish/config.fish'
        search_string: krew
        line: set --append --export --global PATH $HOME/.krew/bin
   ```
2. Then, use the `shell` module to **source Fish config file** and run `kubectl` commands to install my plugins:

   ```
   - name: Install `kubectx` (context) and `kudens` (namespace)
      shell: |
        source {{ home }}/.config/fish/config.fish
        kubectl krew install ctx
        kubectl krew install ns
        kubectl krew install oidc-login
      args:
        executable: /usr/bin/fish
   ```

#### Disclaimer

Look a bit hack-ish to me, would love more ansible-ish solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set env with a custom [become plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/become.html)

**hosts setting**

```
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=foo
```

**become_plugins/foo.py**

```py
from ansible.plugins.become import BecomeBase

class BecomeModule(BecomeBase):
    def build_become_command(self, cmd, shell):
        cmd = 'PYTHONPATH="/foo/bar:$PYTHONPATH" ' + cmd
        return cmd
```