# How can I set NODE_ENV permanently with ansible?

Tags: node.js, environment, production, ansible

I have 2 machines for my two environments.

The first one hosts a *staging* environment. It needs to have `NODE_ENV` set to `dev`.

The second one hosts a *production* environment. It needs to have `NODE_ENV` set to `prod`.

I provision my servers with Ansible.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

Another option is set `NODE_ENV` at `/etc/environment` file.

In ansible tasks:

`- lineinfile: dest=/etc/environment line="NODE_ENV=dev"`

Comment: The issue I have with this answer is that it will append NODE_ENV=dev every time the playbook is run. Which can ultimately lead to a large environment file

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem like so.

In `roles/node-env/tasks/main.yml` :

```
---
- name: Configure NODE_ENV
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/environment regexp="^NODE_ENV=" line="NODE_ENV={{ node_env }}"
  when: node_env is defined
```

In `hosts/staging`:

```
[webserver]
staging-server-hostname

[webserver:vars]
node_env=dev
```

In `hosts/production`:

```
[webserver]
production-server-hostname

[webserver:vars]
node_env=prod
```

In `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- name: Provision web server
  hosts: webserver
  sudo: true
  roles:
    - { role: Stouts.nodejs, tags: nodejs }
    - ...
    - { role: node-env, tags: nodejs }
```

Then I provision my staging environment with:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts/staging playbook.yml
```

And my production environment with:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts/production playbook.yml
```

Note that I stored my environment variable in `/etc/environment` because I wanted this variable set one for all and for every users.

This can also be stored in `~/.profile` or in  `/etc/profile.d` according to your needs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27736434/2590861) for more information.

It might be overkill, but it's flexible. If anyone has a simplier suggestion don't hesitate to share!