# How to set environment variables of remote hosts

Tags: linux, environment-variables, ansible

I am having problems working with the environment variables of a remote host. For example, when I try {{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }} this returns the path of my guest machine not of the remote host.

How to pick up / change environment variables of the remote host?

my playbook :

```
---
- name : playbook
  hosts : webservers
  gather_facts: yes
  remote_user: user1
  vars:
   Path: "{{lookup('ansible_env','PATH')}}"
  roles :
 - task1
 - task2 
 - task3
```

that's return the path of my machine not the path of remote host named user1 
i'm a beginner in ansible need some help .
thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your task, inventory and how you are calling Ansible?

Comment: my play-book contain only those lines : 
---
 - name: Set Path for java
   command: bash -c "export $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733511/how-to-set-linux-environment-variables-with-ansible/27736434#27736434

Answer (score 8):

You can set the PATH for a task or a playbook by using the environment keyword.

```
environment:
  PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/thingy/bin"
  SOME: value
```

The Ansible FAQ mentions this near the top http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html

So in your case try something like the following:

```
- name: Set Path for java
  environment:
    PATH: "$JAVA_HOME/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```

Setting the environment reference: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html

Comment: to work for example with the  PATH  of the remote host named "vagrant" .i write 
environment:
  PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/vagrant/bin" ?? 
@wazy

Comment: That would add /vagrant/bin to the PATH on the hosts you have specified this task under.

Comment: i itried to use "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}" but it return the PATH of my machine . i want to have the PATH of the remote  host  mentioned in the file /etc/ansible/hosts not the Path of my machine in which i installed ansible .

Comment: Are you running the tasks under a play that specifies your remote host? Please show your play.

Comment: i changed my post .in which you can see my  playbook