# How to set existing linux environment variables with ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible v2.4.0.0 on RHEL 6.x

I see [How to set linux environment variables with ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733511/how-to-set-linux-environment-variables-with-ansible), but it deals with setting a NEW environment variable. The solution does NOT work for me if I try to set my PATH variable. I do...

```
- name: Add /usr/other/bin to PATH dir to use the git binary there
  environment:
#    PATH: /usr/other/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}
    PATH: /usr/other/bin:{{ lookup('env','PATH') }}
```

I've tried both ways, shown above, commenting out one vs. the other, and I get syntax errors in both cases. What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the correct way to extend `PATH` variable for a single task:

```
- name: Execute task with extended PATH
  shell: echo $PATH
  environment:
    PATH: "/usr/other/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```

`environment` is not an action by itself, it's a keyword to modify actions' (`shell` in my example) environment.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.

Comment: Adding this here in case someone runs into the same problem. Make sure `gather_facts: true` for your playbook. If it's set to false, your PATH variable will NOT be set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but [Konstantin Suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46937169/7841715) solution doesn't work for me.

After some tests I used following Ansible part in combination with Vagrant (Ubuntu guest).

```
-name: Creating environment variable via file in /etc/profile.d
 args:
   chdir: /etc/profile.d
 shell: echo "export M2_HOME=/home/vagrant/maven" > env.sh
```

This works with `PATH`, too, by adding it into the quotes with `${PATH}`.

Comment: I had the same problem but found the solution - make sure `gather_facts: true`. Konstantin's solution should work.