# Webpack out of memory

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I'm working with a webpack-dev server, the problem sometimes occurs

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

more [here](https://pastebin.com/Rq4w3YXJ)

Config [webpack.config.js](https://pastebin.com/1VrJpfaY)

```
"webpack": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3",
```

NodeJS version:

```
node -v
v9.3.0
```

OS version:

```
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Little information is available, this probably is a memory leak in Webpack or a npm package. I got this behaviour after upgrading to Webpack 4.16 from 3.x. If I find anything I will let you know

Answer (score 13):

```sh
node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
```

Run above command instead of running **`npm start`**

Answer (score 8):

Increase your node process's memory limit. Start `node` with command-line flag `--max-old-space-size=2048` (to 2GB, default is 512 MB I think), or set it via environment variable `NODE_OPTS` https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html

Comment: Please note that the actual link is: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_optionsoptions . `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=2048` something like that

Answer (score 5):

You might get away with the following. The issue is caused by a memory leak in postcss-loader. The one liner below has worked for some.

```
rm -rf [package-lock.json] node_modules && npm cache clean -f && npm i
```

For more information: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6929

Comment: This is vague - what version of postcss-loader has the memory leak? Reinstalling every module because you have a problem with one isn't a good fix.

Comment: @mikemaccana This issue is over almost 3 years old, I can't remember the specifics, but the line above automagically fixed it for me after wasting hours on finding the exact issue.

Comment: Sure but it's like reinstalling your OS or getting a new laptop - it might fix the issue, but it's not much of an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the solution suggested above of using webpack-dev-server but it hangs(?) or maybe it runs a server. Looking inside my webpack script (version 4.43.0) I did this instead:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
```

this worked locally and in my jenkinsfile. Run this instead of "webpack"

Answer (score 0):

I got another approach from here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/114885/diffs?commit_id=edf538c8142c34a07d43d0b6f5dee0250879414c
It says it can help with out of memory errors during compilation.

I used command like this:

```
"NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4094\" webpack --watch --env.type development --env.analysis 1"
```

You can use command like this:

```
"NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=[memory-limit-in-megabytes]\" webpack [your-parameters]"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34783774)

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the link doesn't give much information. I can only add more from myself.

Comment: @patrickmdnet Thanks for the advice. I don't have a lot of experience with answers, so if anything else stabs you in the eye, please post.