# Heap out of memory - increasing max-old-space-size didn't solve the issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm working on a quite huge react application and have recently encountered the following problem:

When I start my app with npm start it works just fine and nothing seems wrong, even though I get

```
   FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

From time to time in my console output, which doesn't really prevent my app from running. However, when I try to actually build my app, the very same error appears and build folder doesn't contain all the files. I've tried increasing --max-old-space-size up to 32GB, though it didn't really help.

Full output:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[360:000001C14A7A3D80]    58555 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1993.9 (2033.6) -> 1993.9 (2033.1) MB, 615.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.685, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
[360:000001C14A7A3D80]    59180 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1993.9 (2005.1) -> 1993.7 (2005.1) MB, 625.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.510, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7F282052F napi_wrap+109311
 2: 00007FF7F27C5256 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+33302
 3: 00007FF7F27C6026 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF7F309163E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7F30764BD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF7F2F2094C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF7F2F1BD61 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1569
 8: 00007FF7F2F35F06 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+166
 9: 00007FF7F2F49924 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller+84
10: 00007FF7F2F49C23 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithMap+35
11: 00007FF7F2D50D6C v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap,2>::Allocate+124
12: 00007FF7F2D5356B v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap,2>::Rehash+59
13: 00007FF7F2D5234A v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap,2>::EnsureGrowable+90
14: 00007FF7F2C89837 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+122119
15: 00007FF7F3119FED v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+463949
```

Moreover, it happens in few environments. Both on my local machine and when I try to build it through Gitlab CI/CD

Comment: What bundler are you using and which version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536623/webpack-out-of-memory)

Comment: Sure, I've tried to use different scenarios in my app, but the memory didn't exceed even 100MB mark. Not really familiar with the bundler part, as it seems like there's no webpack, but typescript is used as a bundler.

Comment: max-old-space-size doesn't help. I tried to run build/dev-server with max-old-space-size = 32000 and also set it as my local node env. Didn't make any difference

Comment: Maybe you could run a debugger, to see what happens when. There might be a memory leak somewhere