# Automatically include environment variables in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that performs various tasks based on environment variables that have been set on the system running Ansible. For example:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Download allowlist
    command: "some_command {{ lookup('env', 'ALLOWLIST_URL') }}"
    when: "lookup('env', 'ALLOWLIST_URL') is defined"
```

Currently, I provide all the environment variables from outside the playbook, through a wrapper script:

```
export ALLOWLIST_URL="..."
export SOME_OTHER_VAR="..."
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yaml
```

However, I'd like to be able to include these environment variables automatically into Ansible, either through a command line switch, an additional task in the playbook, or another means, so that I can get rid of the wrapper entirely.

To clarify, I'd prefer a way of doing something like this (this is not a real command and only intended to demonstrate what I'm looking for):

```
ansible-playbook --include-env-vars ENVFILE -i hosts playbook.yml
```

Or, if it's within the playbook, something like this (again, `include_env_vars` is not a real module and only intended as a demonstration):

```
tasks:
- name: Include env vars
  include_env_vars:
    from: ENVFILE
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Clarify the use case, please. The environment, you provide by the wrapper, is available to the localhost. Shall other hosts (- hosts: all) see this environment too?

Comment: Just put them before the ansible call, separated by semicolons : `export ALLOWLIST_URL="..."; export SOME_OTHER_VAR="..."; ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yaml`   Is that really any worse than command-line arguments?

Comment: Does [How to set Linux environment variables with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733511/) answer your question?

Comment: @U880D I've realized that I would probably be better served by moving off from environment variables to native Ansible variables to fulfill this use case as there is `include_vars` for Ansible variables.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables are facts gathered with setup. Each user on each host potentially has a different set of relevant environment variables with specific values defined. On the Ansible controller you could run this playbook:

```bash
$ ansible-playbook env.yml -i localhost, -v
```

**Sample code env.yml**

```yaml
---
- name: Gather environment variables
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Gather env facts
      ansible.builtin.setup:
        gather_subset: env

    - name: Display ansible_env
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        verbosity: 1
        msg: "{{ ansible_env }}"
```